# XWalkResourceClient.shouldInterceptLoadRequest seems not working properly

Tags: android, networking, crosswalk-runtime, intercept, crosswalk

I'm trying to override url loading. Custom http requests are implemented through okhttp library. App seems starting fine but right after start it closes. I've double checked that returned mime-type set as text/html and so on. So where is a problem? Here is my code:

```
public class MyXWalkResourceClient extends XWalkResourceClient {
    @Override
    public XWalkWebResourceResponse shouldInterceptLoadRequest(XWalkView view, XWalkWebResourceRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> headers = request.getRequestHeaders();
        headers.put("Accept-Language", "ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");

        Request okHttpRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .url(request.getUrl().toString())
                .headers(Headers.of(headers))
                .build();

        Response okHttpResponse = null;
        try {
            okHttpResponse = client.newCall(okHttpRequest).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (okHttpResponse == null) {
            return null;
        }

        XWalkWebResourceResponse resourceResponse = createXWalkWebResourceResponse(
                okHttpResponse.body().contentType().toString().split(";")[0],
                okHttpResponse.body().contentType().charset().name(),
                okHttpResponse.body().byteStream(),
                okHttpResponse.code(),
                okHttpResponse.message(),
                toRegularMap(okHttpResponse.headers().toMultimap()));
        return resourceResponse;
    }

    private Map<String, String> toRegularMap(Map<String, List<String>> multimap) {
        Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : multimap.entrySet()) {
            resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), TextUtils.join(",", entry.getValue()));
        }
        return resultMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. Seems answer was simple. I just need to check to null this expression: `okHttpResponse.body().contentType().charset()`